# Knockout data-bind in checkbox not working on android (4.2)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

There is an issue with data binding in my html control using Knockout JS:

I have following input checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chbText" data-mini="true" data-bind="checked: chkAddLabel"  />
```

I have bind chkAddLabel property to show/hide some div using following code

```
 this.IsShowDiv = ko.computed(function () {
     return this.chkAddLabel();
 }
```

and finally the div

```
<div data-bind="visible: IsShowDiv"></div>
```

This same code is working fine on Windows OS browsers (Chrome, IE, firefox) but not working on Nexus 7 and Nexus 5.

Comment: Could you put together an example in jsFiddle to duplicate the problem?

Comment: Make sure what release of Knockout you are using.Read in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/browser-support.html and run test suit to know its support or not. If it's not supported, then create issue in there github account

Comment: Not sure why you need a computed variable IsShowDiv which just returns the chkAddLabel value? Seems redundant

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the `this` variable to local variable. Suppose consider it as `self`. We need to do this because every function having default variable `this`
because of the parent `this` is override with new `this`.

```
var self = this;
self.IsShowDiv = ko.computed(function () {
 return self.chkAddLabel();
}
```